# reactJS - insert a component in to DOM after render

Tags: reactjs

I am using `React-Day-Picker` to create an appointment booking tool. Currently, the output looks like this.

[image: current]

However the client would like the timeslots to display below the relevant week that has been selected like so:

[image: desired]

The question is how can i achieve this?
I capture the onclick event whent user selects a date:

```
const handleDayClick = (day, { selected }, e) => {
    const weekDIV = e.target.closest('.DayPicker-Week')

    // non react way would be something like this
    const test = document.createElement('div')
    weekDIV.after(test)

 // thought maybe portal would work?
    //ReactDOM.createPortal(weekDIV, document.createElement('div'))
}
```

Nb: the timeslots are a component and not related to `react-day-picker`

I have set up a small example here: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-goldstine-o6qvs?file=/src/App.js)

appreciated any guidance.

thanks

Comment: My first thought was - use a Portal. Have you tried that?

Comment: hey, yea I found that after I posted yesterday, but not been able to get it working as of yet, I need to have a deeper read of the concept today.